# In what condition will EWS subscription become invalid?

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices

I use EWS PushNotification to sync calendar events, but get

> "Unable to retrieve events for this subscription.  The subscription
>   must be recreated., The events couldn't be read"

error after some time

**Does anyone know what condition will trigger this error on EWS side?**

Seems Microsoft doesn't document this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common reason is the Mailbox moving which in Office365 can happen quite a bit as they patch and update servers or for load-balancing etc. This is a little old but still relevant https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2008/07/24/transitioning-to-exchange-web-services-notifications/